# Is there a name for: (p => q) => ((p and r) => q)?

Tags: logic, terminology, propositional-calculus

Is there a name for the following inference rule?:

```
If (p => q), then we infer [for all r]: (p and r) => q
```

If so, what is it?

I use the above inference rule so often, it would be handy (efficient) from a documentation point-of-view, to be able to accompany its use with just a name.

I know that this rule is intuitively obvious, and that the proof of it is trivial, but sometimes a comment taking the form of a rule name can stop the reader going off on a tangent in trying to understand how a logic argument has proceeded from one line to the next (especially, if the various terms involved are complicated expressions).

The various 'logic' sites that I looked at, didn't include this rule in their lists of named inference rules (perhaps, because it is readily deduced from  some of the ones that were listed).

Of the many sites I tried, the following two Wikipedia sites seemed to have the most comprehensive listing of inference rules:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference#Table:_Rules_of_Inference

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Basic_and_derived_argument_forms

P.S.
As an aside, if anyone knows of a site that has a listing of named inference rules more comprehensive than the listings provided by the above-mentioned Wikipedia sites, I'd definitely be interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "proof theoretic" version of this rule is called [weakening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_rule). I think it would be acceptable to refer to your version of the rule by the same name.

Comment: Good answer!  I agree with you ... The term 'weakening' (from sequent calculus) really captures the core concept of the inference rule that my question pertains to ... I would feel very comfortable using it.  I'll wait a little bit, just to see if any one is able to offer a recognized term (without recourse to sequent calculus) for the inference rule that I've asked about, but in the absence of such a recognised term being offered, your answer would very likely be the one that I accept.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that simply be monotonicity of the implication (in particular, downward monotonicity in the first argument)? See also [non-monotonic logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-monotonic_logic).

Comment: Before your answer, I had not come across use of the term 'monotonicity' within the context of logic-centric subject matter.  I've now Google'd it, and admittedly I don't fully understand it as yet (but I feel that I would, in time) ... I'll continue to give it some thought!  Definitely, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @memexor: Sorry, I should have explained better. Think in terms of the set-theoretic operators corresponding to the propositional connectives, i.e. complement $(.)^c$ for negation, union $\cup$ for disjunction etc. operating on the powerset of a given set. Then implication $A \to B$ is rendered as $A^c \cup B$. This is downwards monotone in the first argument in the sense that if $C \subseteq A$, then $(A^c \cup B) \subseteq (C^c \cup B)$. Thus with $(A\cap D)\subseteq A$ also $(A^c \cup B) \subseteq ((A \cap D)^c \cup B)$. In this sense $A \to B$ implies $(A\wedge D) \to B$ by monotonicity.

Comment: Wow! Now I understand! Thanks for the explanation!  A comment of the form "Monotonicity of implication" would certainly be appropriate for the inference rule mentioned by my question.  Hmmm ... The choice (for naming the inference rule in my original question) so far, seems to be between "Weakening of sequent" (after @goblin) and your "Monotonicity of implication" ... either would be an excellent choice!

Comment: This doesn't seem quite right; isn't implication *antitone* in the first argument?

Comment: @goblin: Either of "Monotonicity of implication" and "Monotonicity of inference" would seem apt, according to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/vc/arxiv/papers/0812/0812.4852v65.pdf) on Direct Logic (see page 12).

Comment: @goblin: I think we think of the same property - your _antitone_ is what I described as _downward monotone_, right (see also my comment above)? Sorry for not making that entirely precise in the answer.

Comment: @Björn, think about it this way. If $a \rightarrow b$, then $(b \rightarrow k) \rightarrow (a \rightarrow k)$. There's a *flip*; $a$ started on the left and wound up on the right. So the function $(- \rightarrow k)$ isn't monotone in general.

Comment: @goblin: I strongly suspect that by _monotone_ you mean what could also be called _upwards monotone_ and by _antitone_ you mean what I called _downwards monotone_. I completely agree that the function $(- \to k)$ is not _upwards monotone_ and in fact also don't mind calling it antitone. In my answer I wrote "monotonicity" for "(upwards resp. downwards) monotonicity". This way the (admittedly not entirely precise) notion of "monotonicity of the implication" also captures that $(A \to B)$ implies $(A \to (B \lor C))$.

Comment: @goblin: I did some more googling, and found two documents ([D1](http://web.stanford.edu/~azaenen/LING-7800-019/LSABoulder1b.pdf) and [D2](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/gries/Papers/Monotonicity.pdf), say) that employ different terminologies (T1 and T2 respectively, say) relating to monotonicity.  Specifically: (i) 'upward monotonicity' in T1 corresponds to 'monotonicity' in T2; (ii) 'downward monotonicity' in T1 corresponds to 'antimonotonicity' in T2.  So, under T1, Björn's statements are correct, and under T2, goblin's statements are correct!

Comment: @memexor, yes I had forgotten about those conventions. For the record, I don't like them. In my opinion, monotone should always mean $x \leq_X x' \rightarrow f(x) \leq_Y f(x').$ This is how order theorists talk. I tend to think that the convention that "monotone" can also mean $x \leq_X x' \rightarrow f(x) \geq_Y f(x')$ is a very old convention that professionals in the area no longer use. They would call this second property "antitone." Also, don't be fooled into thinking these are equally important concepts; they aren't. The composite of monotone maps is monotone, but...

Comment: ...the composite of antitone maps is almost never antitone. So monotone maps form a category, while antitone maps do not; hence monotone maps are really much more important, in my opinion. In any event, I wouldn't call the property you're looking at "antitonicity of $\rightarrow$ in the first argument", since this should be the theorem/axiom that "If $a\rightarrow b$, then $(b\rightarrow k)\rightarrow (a\rightarrow k)$"

Comment: Given the different terminologies that prevail relating to monotonicity, I feel that to use it (the term 'monotonicity') in naming the inference rule mentioned in my original question, could lead to confusion.  In contrast, I couldn't find such a clash of terminologies relating to the concept of weakening in sequent calculus.  Hence, I've decided to name the inference rule mentioned in my original question: 'Weakening of sequent' (after goblin).  Thanks goblin and Björn for your impressive answers and commentaries.

Comment: @memexor, here's an observation based on what Bjorn was saying. Whenever $P$ is a poset, call $L \subseteq P$ a *lowerset* of $P$ iff for all $x,y \in P$, we have that if $x \leq y$ and $y \in L$, then $x \in L$. Then for any fixed $k \in \{0,1\}$, the function $(- \rightarrow k)$ is a map $\{0,1\} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ and can therefore be thought of as a predicate; it can therefore be thought of as a subset $S_k$ of $\{0,1\}$. Then the theorem/axiom of interest can then be interpreted as saying that for all $k \in \{0,1\}$, $S_k$ is lowerset of $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @memexor, exercise (if you know some lattice theory); show that if a poset $P$ has all binary meets, then $L \subseteq P$ is a lowerset iff for all $p \in P$ and all $q \in L$, we have $p \wedge q$ in $L$.

Comment: @memexor, also, if you're interested in logic but don't know any lattice theory, you should *definitely* learn some lattice theory. Lattice theory (and/or semilattice theory) is the correct framework in which to understand propositional logic and its various generalizations.

Comment: @goblin: It's clear to me from your comments that you are way, way more advanced than me when it comes to mathematics/logic.  In intellectual terms, I feel like an amoeba by comparison!  I hope that one day I can attain your level of competency in mathematics and logic (but by then, you will have probably moved on to an even higher level of competency in these areas!). I feel that I'm 'slow' at understanding things, but that once I understand something I can apply it well (because the understanding I struggled to achieve is 'deeper' as a result of that struggle).  Big thanks for your guidance!

Comment: @memexor, haha I also feel that I'm slow at understanding things. And I also think that when I get them, I 'truly' get them. It sounds like we're not so different. :)

Comment: @goblin: Thanks for the additional explanations and apologies for using the older terminology. I have to admit that I don't get why you don't think the property memexor is looking for is antitonicity, though. The header of the question has the axiom $(p \to q) \to ((p \land r)\to q)$. This is essentially of the form $(p \circ q) \to ((p\land r) \circ q)$ for $\circ$ a binary connective which characterises antitonicity of $\circ$ in the first argument. If $\circ$ is implication this is indeed equivalent to the left weakening rule in a standard sequent calculus. But not for other $\circ$.

Comment: @memexor: By the way, the property you are looking for seems to be called simply _monotonicity_ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) (under "Formal Properties")...

Comment: Björn .. The [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) you provided in your previous comment states "Both \to and \vDash are monotonic", and hence asserts "\to is monotonic".  So, on this basis (were I to use the terminology (T*, say) employed in the said reference), 'monotonicity of implication' would seem more apt for my inference rule than just 'monotonicity' (but I recognise that by your use of the sentence fragment "simply monotonicity" in your comment, you may have meant ...

Comment: ... that 'monotonicity of implication' is sufficient for describing my inference rule without any recourse to 'upward' / 'downward' / 'first argument' / etc. being required ... in which case, I agree).  However, the reason I decided not to use T*, is that I encountered (when googling) a reasonably widely used alternative terminology that clashes with it -- For example, my inference rule is effectively called 'Antimonotonicity' [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/gries/Papers/Monotonicity.pdf) (see point 7, at the bottom of page 2).  Thus, ...

Comment: ... depending on which 'school of terminology' is adhered to by a reader of one of my proofs, my using the term 'monotonicity' to describe my inference rule could prove misleading or confusing.  I encountered (when googling) no such clash of terminologies for the concept of 'weakening' in sequent calculus, and hence my opting to use the term 'weakening' in describing my inference rule, instead of 'monotonicity'.

Comment: In a previous comment, I forgot to enclose each of '\to' and '\vDash' within a pair of dollar signs.  That is, in that comment I meant '$\to$' instead of '\to', and '$\vDash$' instead of '\vDash'.

Comment: @memexor: yes, that is what I meant. But fair enough, use whichever terminology you prefer.